# Useful software and/or "manual" method for data analysis in a stylistic study of transitivity (SFL)

Tags: software, methodology, analysis, systemic-functional, transitivity

What would be a useful software and/or systematic "manual" method for data analysis in a study of transitivity (Systemic Functional Linguistics) that would like to incorporate some kind of statistics despite being overall qualitative in nature? I am especially asking for methods and softwares appropriate for linguists with a non-mathematical background. (NB: The software needs to be non-Roman script-friendly)

Thank you very much in advance.